# Why this Regex expression with <delimiter> is not working?

Tags: php, regex

I heave this text:

```
1- Processo: 58701.001618/2014-83
Proponente: Associação Barateiro de Futsal Clube
Título: Escolinha Barateiro Futsal

2- Processo: 58701.001694/2014-99
Proponente: Associação Latina de Desenvolvimento Esportivo, Cultural
e Ambiental
Título: Campeonato Internacional Juvenil de Tênis de Porto Alegre
```

I need this:

```
array(
    0 => 
      1- Processo: 58701.001618/2014-83
      Proponente: Associação Barateiro de Futsal Clube
      Título: Escolinha Barateiro Futsal

  , 
    1 => '
     2- Processo: 58701.001694/2014-99
     Proponente: Associação Latina de Desenvolvimento Esportivo, Cultural
     e Ambiental
     Título: Campeonato Internacional Juvenil de Tênis de Porto Alegre

 ',
 )
```

I heave this Regex but not work:

```
   $publicationsRegex = '~((?<delimiter>(\d{1,3}\-\s)+-).*?(?=(?&delimiter)|\Z))~s';
   preg_match_all($publicationsRegex, $textPage, $matches);
```

Anyone know how to do this using  or otherwise?

Comment: There's no space between the number and hyphen.

Comment: Why not `explode("\n\n", $str)`? Why go to this complex regexp? Unless there's a more complex issue your sample data doesn't show.

Comment: I alredy try like this: '~((?<delimiter>(\d{1,3}\-\s)+-).*?(?=(?&delimiter)|\Z))~s';

Comment: there is another way to do this? without delimiter for example?

Comment: What do you want to do, match number hyphen then everything until a blank line?

Comment: You know o'que does <delimiter>?

Comment: I want to separate text blocks in the way I described above in question

Comment: It is making a named capture group, named `delimiter`.. You haven't described anything above.

Comment: yes! i need  "parse" this group to array like i described above in question

Comment: but my <delimiter> content: (\d{1,3}\-\s)  it is bad. I need your help for make another delimiter